# How to create filter based on alphabet character using PHP and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have created below code to display array values alphabet wise.

```
<?php

$arry = array('Alex', 'Alan', 'Alesso', 'Avici', 'Catherine', 'Calvin', 'Gran', 'David', 
'1001', '11545', '9090');

sort($arry);
echo '<pre>';print_r($arry); ?>

<ul class="listing">
<?php for($c='A',$j=1;$j<=26;$j++) {
$contains2 = false;

foreach($arry as $s) {

    if ($s[0] == $c) {

        $contains2 = true;
    }
}
if($contains2){
?>

        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <?php echo $c; ?>
            </a>
        </li>


<?php   
}
$c++;
} 
?>
    </ul>

<?php for($c='A',$j=1;$j<=26;$j++) {

$contains2 = false;

foreach($arry as $s) {

    if ($s[0] == $c) {

        $contains2 = true;
    }
}

if($contains2){

    echo '<Br/><h2>'.$c.'</h2>';

}


foreach($arry as $s) {

    if ($s[0] == $c) {

        echo $s.' - ';
    }
}
$c++;
}
?>
<style>
.listing{display:inline-flex;width:15px;}
.listing li{float:left;list-style:none;}
</style>
```

Output of above code:
[image]

Now I want below functionality:

When I click on any character which are on the top then only corresponding block of values are shown below

For Ex: when I click on "A" then I want to display only those values which have "A" as a first character and all other values must be hidden.Please refer below screenshot:
[image]

So how can I achieve this using PHP and JavaScript? I think that I have to use more CSS with JavaScript as well

Comment: Half of the code you posted was commented. You might want to format it properly first.

Comment: you could probably implement a little bit of css and js with that

Comment: @Eddie I have edited my answer

Comment: @Ghost Yes that is my question that what type script I have to implement in my code?

Answer (score 1):

Just add a simple hide show mechanism on top of what you have. You can use plain ol' JS with what you already have and manipulate the CSS from there.

Here's the idea:

```
<li>
    <a href="#" onclick="toggleGroup('<?php echo $c; ?>');">
        <?php echo $c; ?>
    </a>
</li>
```

Basically just add a function on click event with each header.

Then add your markers on the text that needs to be hidden and add a class. So that when your function fires, it can distinguish which ones to show and to hide.

```
foreach($arry as $s) {

    if ($s[0] == $c) {

        echo "<span class=\"letter group-{$c}\">{$s} - </span>";
    }
}
```

It'll yield along the lines of something like this:

```
letter group-A 
letter group-B
letter group-C
letter group-... and so on
```

And then finally the script itself.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleGroup(letter) {
    var values = document.querySelectorAll('.letter');
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
        values[i].style.display = values[i].getAttribute('class').indexOf('group-' + letter) !== -1 ? 'inline-block' : 'none';
    }
}
</script>
```

Basically it gets the argument (meaning it gets the letter that you clicked) then checks out all the letters, if its `A`, then all group A classes should be manipulated with display "show" and the if not, then just "hide".

Here's a [fiddle](https://www.tehplayground.com/CCXLrCcbr1BnWe9s) to see it work.

Comment: Can we use any built-in js method instead of "toggleGroup"? I am having some difficulties using this method.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an effective solution without re-inventing the wheel.

There is a great vanilla JavaScript plugin that will alphabetically filter any HTML list with alphabetical navigation, called [AlphaListNav.js](https://elliottprogrammer.github.io/alphaListNav.js/)

Just output your list, either with static HTML or with PHP:

```
<ul id="myList">
  <li>Eggplant</li>
  <li>Apples</li>
  <li>Carrots</li>
  <li>Blueberries</li>  
</ul>
```

Add the CSS in the `<head>` of your page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="alphaListNav.css">
```

Add the JavaScript file just before the closing `</body>` tag:

```
<script src="alphaListNav.js"></script>
```

And then Initialize the AlphaListNav library on your list by passing it the id of your list. Like so:

```
<script>
    new AlphaListNav('myList');
</script>
```

It has all kinds of different options for customizing the behavior you may want:

For example:

```
<script>
  new AlphaListNav('myList', {
    initLetter: 'A',
    includeAll: false,
    includeNums: false,
    removeDisabled: true,
    //and many other options available..
  });
</script>
```

The GitHub project is [here](https://github.com/elliottprogrammer/alphaListNav.js)

And a CodePen example is [here](https://codepen.io/melliatto/pen/vwWjjj)

The AlphaListNav.js website & documentation is [here](https://elliottprogrammer.github.io/alphaListNav.js/)